# IFrame content Not Displayed in PDF Generated by CFDocument

Tags: iframe, coldfusion

I am using an iframe to display some content which is coming from a url. The content displays correctly in a CF page. However, when I generate a pdf of that page, the pdf does not have the iframe or its contents inside it.

```
<div align="center">
   <iframe src="https://www.example.com/controller.jas?someparam=abc&etc..." 
       align="middle"  
       width="800" 
       height="600" 
       scrolling= "no">
    </iframe>
</div>

</cfsavecontent>

<cfoutput>#LOCAL.Test1#</cfoutput>  

<CFIF FMT is 'P'>
    <cfset pdfReportName="LOCAL.Test1">
    <cfinclude template="../generate_PDF_test.cfm">
```

Comment: pdf's do not contain iframes.

Comment: PDFs cannot contain iframes.

Answer (score 1):

Dunno why neither Dan nor Scott made it an answer.

iframes are an HTML & browser concept. PDFs are neither HTML, nor related to how browsers render HTML.

`<cfdocument>` and its ilk muddy the water slightly as they use HTML to provide document formatting, but that's translated into equivalent PDF formatting when the PDF is generated. It's not like the PDF is actually representing your HTML.

PDF documents are not browser windows, so it doesn't actually make any sense, to think of PDFs "supporting" iframes. It's a meaningless notion.

Comment: (Edit) *PDF documents are not browser windows* True, though techncially if that is *all* he is displaying, he could use `<cfdodument src="http://....">` in place of the iframe. Granted, it is a bit of a crap shoot. @kushi - CFDocument is not the best tool for handling arbitrary html. As Adam said, it is not a browser, so it will not handle everything, and some things not at all - like javascript.

Comment: Yes i get tat pdfs cannot contain an iframe or pdfs are neither related to html but can I make a cfhttp call and retrieve the contents coming from the url so as to display the ulr contents in my pdf or can u plz suggest an alternative

Comment: *Try it*. Why would you ask someone if you can do something instead of using yer own arms and legs and brain to find out for yourself?